# tmux on macOS exits on open in iterm2 or terminal

Tags: tmux, iterm2

I'm unable to open `tmux` in either iTerm2 or Terminal with an empty `tmux.conf`. Splitting windows from a running sessions also fails. (Not that I have any running sessions any more.) In iTerm2 I get one of three possible responses; with Terminal only two. (I've also tried the example tmux.conf that tmux ships with. Same results).

### in iTerm2

```bash
[jayed@merlot ~/jank]  tmux -f ./none.conf                                                                                                                     
[exited]
[jayed@merlot ~/jank]  Term2 3.4.15
                                                                                                                            
[jayed@merlot ~/jank]  tmux -f ./none.conf                                                                                                                      
[exited]

[jayed@merlot ~/jank]  tmux -f ./none.conf                                                                                                                      
^[[>0;95;0c^[P>|iTerm2 3.4.15^[\[exited]
```

### in Terminal

```bash
[jayed@merlot ~/jank]  tmux -f ./none.conf                                                                    
[exited]
                                                                                                      
[jayed@merlot ~/jank]  tmux -f ./none.conf                                                                    
^[[>1;95;0c[exited]
```

Answer (score 7):

I'll leave this up to maybe help someone.

This has to do with the tmux 3.3a upgrade pushed to homebrew on 9 JUN 2022. Rolling back to 3.3 solved my problem.

I don't know what the specific issue is.

Comment: I would file this as a bug report. There's nothing meaningful anyone here can do, and it's something that should be fixed, so that this question/answer won't be useful in the long term.

Comment: In my case it kept on failing even after compiling v3.3 from source, I didn't realize that tmux server was already running but I was detached from it. I killed it with `tmux kill-server` and tried tmux again and it worked.

Answer (score 7):

I'm going to re-iterate @mauricio-poppe mentioned. I did a `brew upgrade` while tmux was running, and reopening tmux would result in some bell characters and `Term2 3.4.15` output in my prompt.

To fix this, I ran:

```
tmux kill-server
brew reinstall tmux
```

Now tmux works as expected.

I'm guessing the build/install needed access to something that was locked open while tmux was still running.

Comment: FWIW, I only needed the first command to restore tmux

Comment: Worked for me, I guess upgrading whilst tmux server is running is not the best idea